# Help with identifing replacement parts

Tags: pcb, components, replacement

I am still learning about electronics and was hoping for some help regarding two components I am trying to replace (due to a faulty connector and my stupid fault).

[image: circuit board]

- With the help of @Lundin, they assisted me with identifying part (#1) as a TO-220. Upon further research, I determined it was a Linear Voltage Regulators REGULATOR 8V 1A 4% (Model #: LM7808CT). Based on my research, this part is no longer available and was wondering if I could replace this with another (vendor) part that meets the above requirements.

As for part (#2), I am afraid that I may have damaged it by trying to desolder the component because of a broken trace that lies underneath it that connects to part (#1). While I am figuring out that desoldering is very difficult to achieve, I am thinking of just cutting the pins and removing the PC mount multi (7) pin connector. But before I do so, I want to make sure that I can replace the connector.

Unfortunately, I am unable to locate a schematic for the circuit board and I cannot identify what type of voltage it can handle. I do know however that this circuit board gets most of its power from a 12-Volt RV battery and sometimes through a 120-volt hookup system. To be clear, this circuit board is for an old RV trailer.

- If I remove the component and there is no part number, is there a way to determine what part I need to purchase based on the information above?

Comment: No 7808CT is stil available nearly everywhere as new ones (found about 10 sources in 5seconds in google),  & found infinite number of them on old ones on ebay like sites. You have not made any researches ;) currently while writing here they have stock on digikey/RS/gotronic/aliexpress/banggood/ebay/etc....

Comment: Surely you can manage some better pictures of the connector? And perhaps tell us what it's meant to connect to and show pictures of that too?

Comment: By the way, a "TO-220" isn't a part at all, it's a package (a "shape" of a part, if you like). There are a LOT of components available in TO-220 packages.

Comment: It appears that everyone missed the part where I said (I am still learning about electronic). Thanks for pointing out they are still available, despite the product is no longer manufactured. I must have missed the substitute section.